# How to avoid Σ turning to S when we compile in plsql?

Tags: plsql

We are tying to use the Σ symbol in our plsql packages. When we compile the packages and execute , the Σ symbol turns to 'S'. Is there any method to avoid this ?

Here is an example:

```
declare 
-- Local variables here
i varchar2(10);
begin

dbms_output.put_line('hello - Σ   ');
end;
```

output

```
hello - S
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a valid ASCII character so you need to use unicode, e.g.:

```
dbms_output.put_line('hello - ' || unistr('\03A3') || '   ');
```

Note that dbms_output may not show the correct character depending on your character set.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL source code is saved to database in [database character set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/fundamentals.htm#CIHEGGJG). Databases that use UTF-8 can use UTF-8 also in PL/SQL source code:

```
with nls_parameters as (
  SELECT 1 as depth, 'SESSION'  as "LEVEL", parameter, value FROM nls_session_parameters
  union all
  SELECT 2 as depth, 'INSTANCE' as "LEVEL", parameter, value FROM nls_instance_parameters
  union all
  SELECT 3 as depth, 'DATABASE' as "LEVEL", parameter, value FROM nls_database_parameters
)
select "LEVEL", parameter, '''' || value || '''' as value
  from nls_parameters
 where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
 order by parameter, depth
;

LEVEL    PARAMETER        VALUE
-------- ---------------- ----------
DATABASE NLS_CHARACTERSET 'AL32UTF8'
```

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.sql
create procedure foo is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('hello - Σ   ');
  dbms_output.put_line('μεταφρασμένο από το Google!');
end;
/
$

SQL> @/tmp/foo

Procedure created.

SQL> exec foo
hello - Σ
μεταφρασμένο από το Google!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Another example:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.sql
create procedure fooΣ is
  Σ number := 100;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('hello - Σ = ' || Σ);
  dbms_output.put_line('μεταφρασμένο από το Google!');
end;
/

SQL> @/tmp/foo

Procedure created.

SQL> exec fooΣ
hello - Σ = 100
μεταφρασμένο από το Google!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Note that I'm using linux terminal that understands UTF-8.