# NVARCHAR2 constants in package specification

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to add a constant in package specification with `nvarchar2` datatype but after compilation it stores in database something like `???`. For example I try to add a constant for armenian word `մեկ`

```
x constant nvarchar2(3) default 'մեկ';
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem or it is impossible to do so?

Comment: What is the database character set and national character set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid Σ turning to S when we compile in plsql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519203/how-to-avoid-%ce%a3-turning-to-s-when-we-compile-in-plsql)

Comment: @JustinCave nls_characterset = WE8MSWIN1252
and nls_nchar_characterset = AL16UTF16

Comment: Did you verify encoding server UTF-8 ?

Comment: @user3489875 Please specify, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Package code is stored in `nls_characterset`. `WE8MSWIN1252` cannot store the characters you are asking it to. In translation to WE... the characters not representable became `?`s.

Comment: @user3489875 Of course he didn't. He already gave us the character sets, neither was AL32UTF8, nor the misnamed UTF8 (which, on Oracle, is CESU-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested you example on two different databases with different `NLS_CHARACTERSET` configurations.

Configurations (recived by query -

```
select * 
 from v$nls_parameters 
 where parameter in ('NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET','NLS_CHARACTERSET','NLS_LANGUAGE')
```

):

First:

```
+----+------------------------+----------+
| id |        PARAMETER       |  VALUE   |
+----+------------------------+----------+
| 1  | NLS_LANGUAGE           | AMERICAN | 
| 2  | NLS_CHARACTERSET       | AL32UTF8 | 
| 3  | NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET | AL16UTF16| 
+----+------------------------+----------+
```

Second:

```
+----+------------------------+-------------+
| id |        PARAMETER       |    VALUE    |
+----+------------------------+-------------+
| 1  | NLS_LANGUAGE           | RUSSIAN     | 
| 2  | NLS_CHARACTERSET       | CL8MSWIN1251| 
| 3  | NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET | AL16UTF16   | 
+----+------------------------+-------------+
```

And the result is following, on DB with charset `AL32UTF8` variable displays correctly, on charset `CL8MSWIN1251` with questions '???'.

I haven't change charsests on databases to validate my suggestion. So I suggest you  change `NLS_CHARACTERSET`  to `AL32UTF8` it should help.

My package for tests:

```
create or replace package question27577711 is
  x constant nvarchar2(3) default 'մեկ';
  function get_constant_x return nvarchar2;
end question27577711;

create or replace package body question27577711 is
  function get_constant_x
  return nvarchar2
  is
  begin
   return x;
  end get_constant_x;
end question27577711;

select question27577711.get_constant_x from dual
```